# Plone hangs on Python's waiter.acquire() and uses 100% CPU

Tags: python, python-2.7, plone, zope, plone-4.x

We are experience some bottle-necking in our Plone instance when content managers perform actions such as Check out, Edit, Workflow transitions, and so on. So far we have not been able to isolate anything specific, and it happens intermittently.

For my own testing, I stuck to the "Check out" action, and I am using Products.LongRequestLogger in my troubleshooting. I am seeing the action take anywhere from 8 seconds to 78 seconds in the logged results as well as the user experience. Here is the traceback that is repeated in the LongRequestLogger:

```
Traceback:
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.21-py2.7.egg/ZServer/PubCore/ZServerPublisher.py", line 31, in __init__
    response=b)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.21-py2.7.egg/ZPublisher/Publish.py", line 455, in publish_module
    environ, debug, request, response)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.LongRequestLogger-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/Products/LongRequestLogger/patch.py", line 16, in wrapper
    result = wrapper.original(*args, **kw)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.21-py2.7.egg/ZPublisher/Publish.py", line 249, in publish_module_standard
    response = publish(request, module_name, after_list, debug=debug)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.21-py2.7.egg/ZPublisher/Publish.py", line 138, in publish
    request, bind=1)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.21-py2.7.egg/ZPublisher/mapply.py", line 77, in mapply
    if debug is not None: return debug(object,args,context)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.21-py2.7.egg/ZPublisher/Publish.py", line 48, in call_object
    result=apply(object,args) # Type s<cr> to step into published object.
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/zeocluster/src/plone.app.iterate/plone/app/iterate/browser/checkout.py", line 77, in __call__
    wc = policy.checkout(locator())
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/zeocluster/src/plone.app.iterate/plone/app/iterate/policy.py", line 65, in checkout
    working_copy, relation = copier.copyTo( container )
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/zeocluster/src/plone.app.iterate/plone/app/iterate/copier.py", line 54, in copyTo
    wc = self._copyBaseline( container )
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/zeocluster/src/plone.app.iterate/plone/app/iterate/copier.py", line 211, in _copyBaseline
    result = container.manage_pasteObjects( clipboard )
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.21-py2.7.egg/OFS/CopySupport.py", line 235, in manage_pasteObjects
    self._setObject(id, ob)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.BTreeFolder2-2.13.3-py2.7.egg/Products/BTreeFolder2/BTreeFolder2.py", line 455, in _setObject
    notify(ObjectAddedEvent(ob, self, id))
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.event-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/event/__init__.py", line 31, in notify
    subscriber(event)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.component-3.9.5-py2.7.egg/zope/component/event.py", line 24, in dispatch
    zope.component.subscribers(event, None)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.component-3.9.5-py2.7.egg/zope/component/_api.py", line 136, in subscribers
    return sitemanager.subscribers(objects, interface)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.component-3.9.5-py2.7.egg/zope/component/registry.py", line 321, in subscribers
    return self.adapters.subscribers(objects, provided)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.interface-4.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/zope/interface/adapter.py", line 601, in subscribers
    subscription(*objects)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.component-3.9.5-py2.7.egg/zope/component/event.py", line 32, in objectEventNotify
    zope.component.subscribers((event.object, event), None)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.component-3.9.5-py2.7.egg/zope/component/_api.py", line 136, in subscribers
    return sitemanager.subscribers(objects, interface)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.component-3.9.5-py2.7.egg/zope/component/registry.py", line 321, in subscribers
    return self.adapters.subscribers(objects, provided)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.interface-4.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/zope/interface/adapter.py", line 601, in subscribers
    subscription(*objects)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.21-py2.7.egg/OFS/subscribers.py", line 110, in dispatchObjectMovedEvent
    callManageAfterAdd(ob, event.object, event.newParent)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.21-py2.7.egg/OFS/subscribers.py", line 143, in callManageAfterAdd
    ob.manage_afterAdd(item, container)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.ATContentTypes-2.1.13-py2.7.egg/Products/ATContentTypes/content/document.py", line 196, in manage_afterAdd
    ATCTContent.manage_afterAdd(self, item, container)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.Archetypes-1.9.4-py2.7.egg/Products/Archetypes/BaseContent.py", line 43, in manage_afterAdd
    BaseObject.manage_afterAdd(self, item, container)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.Archetypes-1.9.4-py2.7.egg/Products/Archetypes/BaseObject.py", line 158, in manage_afterAdd
    Referenceable.manage_afterAdd(self, item, container)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.Archetypes-1.9.4-py2.7.egg/Products/Archetypes/Referenceable.py", line 245, in manage_afterAdd
    r.set(self, rrefs[r.getName()])
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.Archetypes-1.9.4-py2.7.egg/Products/Archetypes/Field.py", line 1987, in set
    tool.addReference(instance, uid, self.relationship, **addRef_kw)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.Archetypes-1.9.4-py2.7.egg/Products/Archetypes/ReferenceEngine.py", line 340, in addReference
    annotation._setObject(rID, referenceObject)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.21-py2.7.egg/OFS/ObjectManager.py", line 359, in _setObject
    notify(ObjectAddedEvent(ob, self, id))
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.event-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/event/__init__.py", line 31, in notify
    subscriber(event)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.component-3.9.5-py2.7.egg/zope/component/event.py", line 24, in dispatch
    zope.component.subscribers(event, None)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.component-3.9.5-py2.7.egg/zope/component/_api.py", line 136, in subscribers
    return sitemanager.subscribers(objects, interface)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.component-3.9.5-py2.7.egg/zope/component/registry.py", line 321, in subscribers
    return self.adapters.subscribers(objects, provided)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.interface-4.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/zope/interface/adapter.py", line 601, in subscribers
    subscription(*objects)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.component-3.9.5-py2.7.egg/zope/component/event.py", line 32, in objectEventNotify
    zope.component.subscribers((event.object, event), None)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.component-3.9.5-py2.7.egg/zope/component/_api.py", line 136, in subscribers
    return sitemanager.subscribers(objects, interface)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.component-3.9.5-py2.7.egg/zope/component/registry.py", line 321, in subscribers
    return self.adapters.subscribers(objects, provided)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.interface-4.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/zope/interface/adapter.py", line 601, in subscribers
    subscription(*objects)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.21-py2.7.egg/OFS/subscribers.py", line 110, in dispatchObjectMovedEvent
    callManageAfterAdd(ob, event.object, event.newParent)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.21-py2.7.egg/OFS/subscribers.py", line 143, in callManageAfterAdd
    ob.manage_afterAdd(item, container)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.Archetypes-1.9.4-py2.7.egg/Products/Archetypes/ReferenceEngine.py", line 145, in manage_afterAdd
    rc.catalog_object(self, url)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.Archetypes-1.9.4-py2.7.egg/Products/Archetypes/UIDCatalog.py", line 189, in catalog_object
    ZCatalog.catalog_object(self, obj, uid, **kwargs)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.ZCatalog-2.13.23-py2.7.egg/Products/ZCatalog/ZCatalog.py", line 476, in catalog_object
    update_metadata=update_metadata)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.ZCatalog-2.13.23-py2.7.egg/Products/ZCatalog/Catalog.py", line 320, in catalogObject
    index = self.updateMetadata(object, uid, None)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.ZCatalog-2.13.23-py2.7.egg/Products/ZCatalog/Catalog.py", line 276, in updateMetadata
    while not data.insert(index, newDataRecord):
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ZODB/Connection.py", line 860, in setstate
    self._setstate(obj)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ZODB/Connection.py", line 901, in _setstate
    p, serial = self._storage.load(obj._p_oid, '')
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ZODB/Connection.py", line 1270, in load
    return self._storage.load(oid, '')
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ZEO/ClientStorage.py", line 833, in load
    data, tid = self._server.loadEx(oid)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ZEO/ServerStub.py", line 176, in loadEx
    return self.rpc.call("loadEx", oid)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ZEO/zrpc/connection.py", line 763, in call
    r_args = self.wait(msgid)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ZEO/zrpc/connection.py", line 791, in wait
    self.replies_cond.wait()
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 339, in wait
    waiter.acquire()
```

During this time I notice that the client it is using maxes out at %100 CPU usage, and this causes the site to come to a crawling slow-down if not a complete halt. I have watched this in our production environment which has anywhere from 5 to 40 simultaneous users at any given time. So I tested this in a local install of our site and even with just 1 user I see the same results.

We are running Plone 4.3.2 on a RedHat 5.10 (Tikanga) 64-bit box. My local VM is running CentOS 5.10 with the same Plone version. For our production environment we are running across two servers, one dedicated to running the Zeoserver, and the 2nd is running 4 clients.

I can't figure out why it is hanging here and taking up so many resources. Any suggestions or solutions would be much appreciated!

**UPDATE**
We recently upgraded from Plone 4.2 to Plone 4.3 and it seems like this issue either started at that time, or at least increased significantly. We do use our own custom theme and content types, but they were based off of the ATContentTypes and we made what updates we needed for them to work with Plone 4.3

**EDIT**
I changed the ZEO server logging level to DEBUG, and this was all I got:

```
2014-05-28T14:38:35 (unconnected) disconnected
2014-05-28T14:38:44 new transaction
2014-05-28T14:38:44 (192.168.56.102:54486) ('1') lock: transactions waiting: 0
2014-05-28T14:38:44 (192.168.56.102:54486) Preparing to commit transaction: 2 objects, 763 bytes
2014-05-28T14:38:44 new transaction
2014-05-28T14:38:44 (192.168.56.102:54486) ('1') lock: transactions waiting: 0
2014-05-28T14:38:44 (192.168.56.102:54486) Preparing to commit transaction: 1 objects, 123 bytes
2014-05-28T14:39:22 new transaction
2014-05-28T14:39:22 (192.168.56.102:54474) ('1') lock: transactions waiting: 0
2014-05-28T14:39:22 (192.168.56.102:54474) Preparing to commit transaction: 885 objects, 458894 bytes
2014-05-28T14:40:44 new transaction
2014-05-28T14:40:44 (192.168.56.102:54486) ('1') lock: transactions waiting: 0
2014-05-28T14:40:44 (192.168.56.102:54486) Preparing to commit transaction: 1 objects, 123 bytes
```

According to Client1 LongRequest.log the action (Check out) started at 14:39:07 and ended at 14:39:28 (this was one of the faster response times).

Comment: What is your ZEO server doing at that point? The traceback terminates in the ZEO connection (RPC) handling.

Comment: I don't see any activity in zeoserver.log and nothing is coming up in LongerRequestLogger for the zeoserver either, even when it does happen on the client. Is there a better or more detailed way I can monitor the activity on the ZEO?

Comment: Could the size of the DB have anything to do with the speed? Our Data.fs is up to 19GB by now, and it is packed each night. We have another Plone site (the setup is exactly the same, only the content differs) and its DB is only 993MB, and we are not seeing these slowdown issues there.

Comment: No, the `Data.fs` is indexed and mostly treated as append-only. I've worked with far larger data sizes.

Comment: That said, it's been a while since I worked with Plone proper and the muscle memory is all a little stiff.

Comment: Do you know of any other reporting or logging tools that might help find the culprit?

Comment: I'd install https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.signalstack, and when another such long hang takes place, send a *USR1* signal to have it dump traces for all threads. It could be that it's a *different* thread that is blocking here.

Comment: Awesome. I'll try that first thing in the morning. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, forgive my inexperience in Linux, but I'm not sure I am understanding correctly. I tried sending the signal to say client1 (using the kill command to send the signal??), and the event.log shows that it received the signal, but I do not see a stacktrace dump anywhere. Should I be monitoring a specific file, or running the client in debug or something?

Comment: Yes, `kill` sends the signal. The *console* (e.g. stdout or stderr) receives the stack traces. How are you running `client1`?

Comment: I tried running client1 with the standard run command, and then tried running in fg. Also tried changing the event-log-level to debug. I haven't tried running it in debug yet though.

Comment: `fg` is running in debug mode. Last time I used the tool it was under supervisord and it would redirect the output to log files; can't recall if it is to stdout or stderr however.